# PhoneGap iOS can't play video using HTML 5

Tags: ios, html, cordova, video, phonegap-build

I'm building phonegap app and I need to play video in it. I know in order to play video on Android, I need to use one of the plugins available, but to play video on iOS, I can use HTML 5 video tag. I have these lines of code:

```
 <div id="video">
    <video id="video01" width="300" height="300" controls>
        <source src="images/test2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</div>
```

I can see "video box", but I cannot play video for some reason. In console I don't see any errors.

Video I'm using is from this page: http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/tests/video.html

And in iPhone Safari I can load MP4 version from that page without any problems.

Comment: What happens if you set it to autoPlay?

Comment: The same thing, i.e. nothing happens

Comment: Which version of iOS are you using? There's a few SO posts that suggests early versions of iOS v8.0 have broken video playback in a webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it has been a while, but I was looking at some of my old questions, and I've noticed that I completely forgot to post solution to my problem.

In the end I've managed to fix the issue using Cordova File api, and solution looks smth. like this:

```
 window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSystem) {
                console.log("gotFS");


                getFolder(fileSystem, "video", function(folder) {
                    filePath = folder.toURL() + "\/" + "videotest.mp4";

                    playVideo(filePath);

                }, function() {
                    console.log("failed to get folder");
                });

            },
            function() {
                console.log("failed to get filesystem");
            });



function playVideo(uri) {


        var player = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
        var source = document.createElement("source");

        source.src = uri;
        source.type = "video/mp4";

        player.appendChild(source);
        player.load();
    }
```