# Cordova Camera on IOS return file_uri with .MOV instead of .MP4

Tags: ios, cordova

Im trying to get video with cordova camera plugin 2.2.1-dev on IOS.
this is my code:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(GotVideo, ErrorVideo, {
    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.VIDEO
});

function GotVideo(src) {
    console.log("SRC: " + src);
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(src, function (fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function (file) {
            console.log("Full Path: " + file.fullPath);
            console.log("Name: " + file.name);
            console.log("Type: " + file.type);
            console.log("Size: " + file.size);
    });
}

function ErrorVideo() {
    ;
}
```

The problem is, I selected MP4 video but the returned src was "file:///private/var/mobile/Container/~~~/tmp/trim.~~~.MOV",

**Name** => trim.~~~.MOV

**FullPath** and **Type** => null

Can someone explain **why .MP4 can be selected as .MOV**?

I tried other videos with .MP4 but always return .MOV with different size

Note: *I selected .MOV video at the first before trying to select .MP4 videos*

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have control over the video encoding when using camera plugin. The video files will always be .MOV for iOS unless they provide such an option in the future.

As you can see in the documentation there is an option for the photo encoding type but not for video.

More info on [the camera-plugin documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera)

Comment: Oh, I see.. is there any solution to get mp4 video from IOS with cordova then? I used html5 video to play video in my cordova app, AFAIK mov file cannot be played on it..

Comment: @RaiN there has to be a workaround, check this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279719/phonegap-ios-cant-play-video-using-html-5?rq=1.